# Use async await with timeout

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

As far as I understand async/await, I would expect the following code to print `a` and then `b`, but it does print `b` first. Why doesnt `await` force it to wait for the execution of the first Timeout?

```
(async () => {

await setTimeout(()=>console.log("a"),10);
await setTimeout(()=>console.log("b"),0);

})();
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise, so you cannot await it.

Comment: @vstm thanks, that's a much better duplicate :-)